# Hide DIV in asp:Panel?

Tags: asp.net, css, html, panel

This is a simple question i guess....

I have a panel that i can turn on and off. Within this panel i have a div with style attached to it.

My problem is when i turn the visible of the panel to false the style of the div is still there. What the solution to this?

Regards

---

```
<div id="ctl00_FullContentRegion_xFormRightPanel"> 
<div class="contactform form-orange" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px; width: 462px;"> 
</div> 
</div>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Panel ID="xFormRightPanel" runat="server">
            <div class="contactform form-orange" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px; width: 462px;">
            <EPiServer:Property ID="Property3" PropertyName="XformRight" runat="server" />
            </div>
            </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Can you paste the resulting HTML when the panel is off?

Comment: @andy, How do you hide it ? with javascript or on code behind. Can you give us some code ? The style of the div is where ? Do you see the div ?

Comment: <div id="ctl00_FullContentRegion_xFormRightPanel">
 
            <div class="contactform form-orange" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px; width: 462px;">
            
            </div>
            
</div>

Comment: @Aristos, I hide it in code behind with panelName.visible = false;

Comment: You say the style of the div is there, but do you mean that the div is still visible or just that its style affects the document?

Comment: Can you update your post with HTML from both states, visible and hidden? And I mean from browser show source, not aspx source.

Comment: @David, when the panel is turned off i can still se the background color of the div.

Comment: The div in your example does not have a background-color attribute, where does the background come from and could it be that it affects other elements also?

Comment: The background color comes from class="contactform form-orange"

Comment: How does the page source look when panel is hidden?

Comment: This is the hidden source
<div id="ctl00_FullContentRegion_xFormRightPanel"> <div class="contactform form-orange" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px; width: 462px;"> </div> </div>

Comment: But that source does not appear to be hidden? What changes in the browsers source version when you set panel to hidden.

Comment: Problem solved! It was a mistake from my side. I just needed to add another visible=false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this action happening on a postback?  If so make the panel invisible **from the server side**

```
<asp:Panel ID="xFormRightPanel" visible="false" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

This will ensure everything within the panel is not rendered at all on the browser.

From what I can understand above you are possibly already doing this so just run over these points:

- Have you double checked where you've
  closed the panel?
- Does it contain the
  elements you expect?
- You're not
  looking at another element (somewhere
  else in the HTML) that you've
  mistaken for this?

Comment: thanks for your tips. I was a mistake from my side. I needed to add another visible=fale in an if-statement.

Comment: @Andy - No problem at all, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing its visibility, change its CSS display property i.e.

```
panelName.style.display = "none"        // check your syntax
```

since items with the hidden visibility property are not shown, but still take space on the page where as items with display:none property will be hidden completely, and will take no space.